# Wall of Flesh didn't make a box

Tags: terraria-console

I killed the Wall of Flesh and it (if I understand correctly) was supposed to make a box with items in it but it didn't. It either fell in lava or The Wall of Flesh didn't drop anything. I'm playing this on Xbox 360. Do you know what happened?

Comment: Seems highly unlikely. The box would always spawn above the current level of the player. It would be made of bricks, and the loot (with exception of the potion and coins) are of sufficient rarity that it wouldn't be destroyed by lava.

Comment: The Terraria wiki lists this as a known bug

Answer (score 3):

The Terraria Wiki [lists this as a known bug](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Flesh#Bugs). Specifically, it mentions:

> Sometimes after beating WoF, it might not drop loot.

Unfortunately this means that you're going to have to kill it again to get any loot.